# Error: Unable to access jarfile myfile.jar

Tags: java, batch-file, executable-jar

I've been trying to run a batch file using the following java code and the above error is thrown on the console

```
               Process run = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start D\\myfile.bat");
```

The batch file when ran independently is running fine, its just misbehaving when called from this code.
what can I do to resolve this?

Comment: You have not posted sufficient information for others to determine what your specific problem is. My assumption is that `myfile.jar` is being called within `D:\myfile.bat`, and that batch file has not defined a current working directory, and is not using the full path to `myfile.jar`. The issue therefore is that you should define the working directory, or use the full path to the `.jar` file. As you are already using the `start` command, perhaps you could use its `/D` option. Please open a Command Prompt window, type `start /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key, to learn how it works.

Comment: Example: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C Start \"\" /D \"D:\\\" \"D:\\myfile.bat\"");` This would run the file with the working directory as ```D:\```. Alternatively, change your batch file by inserting the following line at the top, `@CD /D "D:\"` to define ```D:\``` as the current directory, or if you want it to be the same location as the batch file itself, then use `@CD /D "%~dp0"`. I would generally advise modifying the batch file, as opposed to adjusting the working directory with start, then you could use, `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C Start \"\" \"D:\\myfile.bat\"");`.

Comment: Ravjot Singh, how about you write up a full and proper answer, containing the coded solution, and referencing within the body text the item or items of my comments which helped you to achieve your end goal. As it currently stands, because there is no official answer, your question will be of no use to future readers, and therefore the StackOverflow community.